# Is it possible to use the icons from Apple Maps in an MKMapView?

Tags: mapkit

I wonder if it is possible to use the standard Apple Maps annotations for restaurants, coffee places, libraries etc, inside an iOS application.

Do I as a developer have access to the annotation images seen below so that I can subclass `MKAnnotationView` and use those images?

Apple Maps:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have API-level access, but check out https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor as a possible way to pull the imagery out of the frameworks. I've used this to grab certain assets for the [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk) to make it look like MapKit.